# Visual Studio 2010 MS Test Inconclusive Test Wasn't Run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to get unit tests running on my project (vs2010 pro, asp.net project with vb.net code behind, .net 4.0). Below is my latest attempt and when I run it I get "Inconclusive:Test wasn't run". What am I doing wrong?

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Web
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Public Class CriteriaCopy

    Private Shared Function ConvertToDBNull(ByVal intGID As Integer) As Object
        Dim result

        If intGID.Equals(0) Then
            result = DBNull.Value
        Else
            result = intGID
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

    <TestClass()>
    Class Test

        <TestMethod()>
        Public Sub ConvertToDBNullTest()
            Dim intGID As Integer = 1
            Dim expected As Object = 1
            Dim actual As Object
            actual = ConvertToDBNull(intGID)
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: What type of project is your project?  Is it a test project or a web application project? How are you trying to execute the tests?

Comment: To answer your question, I tried it both ways and could not get a clean build from the solution. Since that post (and forgetting to come back and answer your question, I'm sorry for that) I have since to a different .sln and .vbproj files and THEY are compiling fine with a test project. Thanks again for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution to my problem. And since that post, I have created a new solution and project which includes a test project and everything compiles without error. I blame my problem on user error.